# Отправка данных на странице без перезагрузки

Tags: post, perl

Отправляю данные в форме следующим образом:

```
<form action="[% Env("CGIHandle") %]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data" id="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="[% Env("Action") %]"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Subaction" value="StoreNew"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="FormID" value="[% Data.FormID | html %]"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ExpandCustomerName" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Тема"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Body" value="Тестовый текст"/> 
</form>
```

При обработке страница перезагружается, есть ли возможность реализации без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **AJAX**:

```
<form action="[% Env("CGIHandle") %]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test">
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="[% Env("Action") %]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Subaction" value="StoreNew"/>
<input type="hidden" name="FormID" value="[% Data.FormID | html %]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ExpandCustomerName" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Тема"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Body" value="Тестовый текст"/> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#test');

    frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Запрос выполнен.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Ошибка.');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: в теге form два id? не срабатывает с ajax

Comment: а можно ли использовать jQuery?

Comment: С id, конечно, ошибся. Вам и надо использовать библиотеку **jQuery**.

Comment: не срабатывает, ничего не происходит.
Подкорректировал исходный код.

Comment: Подкорректировал исходный код с обработкой формы после выбора элемента из списка select ("names"). С этим скриптом работает, но страница обновляется.

Comment: var selectmenu=document.getElementById("names")
    selectmenu.onchange=function(){ //
var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex] 
    if (chosenoption.value!="nothing"){
            document.getElementById(chosenoption.value).submit();
    }
    }